# Is this copy constructor doing a deep copy or shallow copy?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have a class called `Directory` with certain members followed by a copy constructor.

```
class  Directory{

private:
    char * Name;                
    int Telephone_Number;   
    char * Address;             
public:
    Directory (Directory & b)    
    {
        Name = new char [10];   //Just assume that the name will not be greater than                                    //10 characters
        Address = new char [30]; //Same here 
        strcpy (Name, b.Name);
        Telephone_Number = b.Telephone_Number;
        strcpy (Address, b.Address);
    }
};
```

I wanted to know if my copy constructor would perform deep copy or shallow copy. I understand that it is deep copying `Address` and `Name` because new memory is being allocated for them, but what about `Telephone_Number`?

Is my code doing shallow copying or deep copying? Could anyone explain copy constructors in general to me?

Comment: There's no such a thing as "copy copy constructors"

Comment: Typing mistake, sorry.

Comment: But then the question becomes even weirder :) What do you mean by "explain in general and explain specifically"?

Comment: ***DON'T FORGET*** to `delete` the `Name` and `Address` before allocating `new` memory.

Comment: Ignore that bit then, went a bit overboard on asking questions there. Anyway, all I wanted to know is whether in this particular case a deep or a shallow copy is being done.

Comment: Thank you M M., but I didn't forget. There's a destructor lying elsewhere to do just that, :)

Comment: @MM. or rather, *don't forget to convert those `char*` to `std::string` and remove that `new` operator!*

Comment: Also, telephone numbers are strings, and can't in general be represented by integers. For example, mine begins with zero; even if it didn't, it's long enough to overflow a 32-bit value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Telephone_Number` is declared as an `int` in the class and copied by value (no references or pointers or anything), so this constructor is doing a **deep copy**.

Lots of information is available about copy constructors on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) or in any good C++ book, you should read something like that first and then see if you have any other specific questions.

It is probably worth the reading time, there are important rules that govern how copy constructors are used when initializing and assigning objects that you should understand.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously it is deep copying Address and Name because new memory is being allocated for them, but what about Telephone_Number?

An int, like the telephone number, is always deep copied.

> Is my current code doing shallow copy or deep?

Deep

> Could anyone explain copy constructors in general and copy constructors specifically to me?

A compiler-synthesized copy constructor would just generate member by
 member copy, i.e. a pointer value is copied, not its contents. Compiler-synthesized copy constructor is always shallow. Whenever deep copy is required, the class author has to write it (as you did).

Also, the signature of the copy constructor should be corrected to pass
 the original object (here, `b`) by **const** reference to prevent it from accidental modification:

```
Directory (Directory const & b) 
                     ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a deep copy. Your int is copied *by value* and you're not copying a reference or pointer.

Answer (score 0):

**It is a deep copy**. Integers are always copied.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, it is a deep copy.

In general when you use a copy constructor, the idea is to get a deep copy.  Meaning that the copy does not share data with the original.

So Let's look at the following:

```
Directory B = new Directory(A);
A->DoSomething();
B->DoSomething();
```

When I read the above code, I expect that `A->DoSomething()` only affects the data in `A`.  Likewise with `B->DoSomething()`.

However, there can be exceptions to the deep copy rule.  Maybe the data is large, so it might be inefficient to make a copy:

```
class LargeData {
    int* PointerToLargeArray;
}
```

In the case above, you could implement the copy constructor by just copying pointers, rather than the data:

```
LargeData(LargeData& b)
{
    PointerToLargeArray = b->PointerToLargeArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Name = new char [10];
Address = new char [30]; //Same here 
strcpy (Name, b.Name);
strcpy (Address, b.Address);
```

Name and Address will just have the memory address to the actual
string. So when we copy 'Name'/'Address' we have to copy the actual content which is pointed by 'Name'/'Address'.If we do just shallow copy as below,

```
b.Name = Name; 
b.Address = Address;
```

we are just pointing to the data which was created by someone which may also get deleted by that someone.If someone delete the actual content,we will be pointing the content assuming its available.Now the pointer is dangling(Pointing Nothing).
This is why we use copy constructor.

```
Telephone_Number = b.Telephone_Number;
```

'Telephone_Number' is holding the actual value.So shallow copy is enough to copy the value

> Name/Address will have the memory address and shallow copy will copy
>   just the memory address of the actual value.
>
> Telephone_Number will have a integer value and shallow copy will copy
>   that integer value

So the copy constructor is 'PERFECT' doing a deep copy.